# The identity of a name binds to a float is different from the identity of the value

Tags: python-3.x

Below is the code puzzling me:

```
y=3
id(3)  # 1445555280
id(y)  # 1445555280
y=3.1
id(3.1) # 132653722264
id(y)   # 132653720656
```

Why are the identities equal for the case and not equal for the second case?

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Most types behave like your second example.  You create a `float` and assign it to `y`.  You then create a new `float` that happens to have the same value.  The two different objects have different `id`s.  Small `int`s are interned to improve performance in CPython, so all references to an `int` with value `5` are references to the same object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Because

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour of Python in this case is undefined. :-)”.

See [Python Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html), that is to say, anytime u just start an interpreter, the integer numbers from -5 to 256 is placed in as an precondition and they are constant which means their `id` inside memory will change on if the interpreter restarted.

The float number, which is NOT **Plain Integer Objects**, is dynamically created, and will be recycled just after no reference to it by [GC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html?highlight=gc#module-gc).

So, in ur case, the integer will be all the same value, and it will be another value only if u restarted the/another interpreter, and the float(string, etc.) is **Dynamically** created which means every time u create a variable or just a number as below:

`y=3.1`

`x=3.1`

`3.1`

the interpreter will ask a **new** memory to answer ur command, and that's why the `float` is always a new value.

Comment: Thank you, Lau Real and Patrick Haugh, very much for your explanation.

Comment: I want to add a comment regarding the subject. I found a similar description from the book , "Learning Python" by Mark Lutz, page 245 on string. It says "Python internally caches and reuses some strings as an optimization..." So, S1="spam" and S2="spam" causes the code S1 is S2 True.     I tried more examples and found that a string of 'a ' is not one of some strings. When a='a ' , a is not 'a '. Then what is some strings? Are there some specific strings like from -5 to 256 for integers? Thanks a lot.